# Making the responseObject accessible for table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm new to objective -c & still trying to wrap my head around this. Say I have something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[CustomAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/api/feed" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionary] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    }];

    **//Now, how do I get my responseObject out here??**
}
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but basically, I have a controller that will display a certain view. I will also have another controller like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[CustomAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/api/profile" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionary] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        }];

        **//Now, how do I get my responseObject out here??**
    }
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I get the responseObject outside of that block?
2. Is there a way for me to stay authenticated without calling the `[[CustomAPIClient...` block?

Thanks in advance guys.

---

To better explain what I'm doing. I have table view cells:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.meResponseObjectFromAboveCode count];
}
```

So I want to have whats in my response object, show up in my table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks are units of execution. In this case, you are giving this method a block that it can execute once the request returns successfully. So, first of all, you're giving the networking client some code and saying "I want it executed whenever you're done, and also right now." If, in theory, it was possible to have the `responseObject` "out here", it would be nil (or at least not what you want) because after the `getPath` method is executed, it stores the block to be executed later (much later) and then continues on to executing the code right after that method, essentially immediately after you issue the network request, giving it no time to actually make the request, return and make `responseObject` available.

Second, blocks are closures. Meaning, it captures the variables outside it's own scope, but anything passed into it or initialized within it is "enclosed" within it and is invisible outside of it.

Now, to make this point very clear, you *could* get around this by declaring a variable before calling `getPath` like `__block id veryBadIdea;` and then (because of the `__block` modifier) you can change it inside of the block. So, in this bad idea example, you would do `veryBadIdea = responseObject` and then after `getPath` you could do `NSLog(@"%@", veryBadIdea);` and see that it is nil. Why? Because by the time NSLog is called, the network request likely has not even been **sent**. By the time veryBadIdea is assigned the value of `responseObject` the `viewDidLoad` has long since finished and returned.

So, use `responseObject` within the block, cause thats where it's available and that's where (and when) you want any code using it to run.

Comment: Yeah, so in most cases, you have a view controller that is responsible for your table view, that acts as its delegate and data source. It will have an array, stored in an instance variable, of the data the table should display. When the screen represented by the view controller is first presented, that array will be empty, thus so will the table view. You could put up a loading indicator at this point. Then you'd fire off the `getPath` request and in the success block, you would populate your array with the contents of `responseObject`, call `reloadData` on the table view and hide the spinner

Comment: You can modify instance variables within blocks without the __block keyword, just make sure in cases like this, where NSArray is not thread safe, that you modifying it on the main thread, the same place it will be read to populate the table view. example of putting a block back on the main thread: `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ // code for main queue here }];`

Comment: Thank you. You've been of great help